# what are my erc-1155 transactions meaning? somebody airdrops or mints to my wallet

Tags: polygon, erc-1155

I currently made wallet in polygon.

and some erc1155 contract was being made which i do not know.

look below transactions in polygon scan.

There are many erc-1155 tnxs to my wallet. but i do not have any 1155 assets.

[image]

what is my erc-1155 transactions meaning? somebody airdrops or mint to my wallet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People send spam transactions especially on sidechains and L2s and non-ETH L1s where transaction fees are cheap. They have different motivations...sometimes they are address poisoning you (hoping you accidentally copy their address instead of yours the next time you send something). Sometimes they are doing fake airdrops or hoping you confuse the address of the coin they are sending you with the address of a legit coin you want to transact in...like hoping you might mistake their coin with a name similar to USDC with real USDC. Basically you can ignore it but be sure to not copy anything from any of these fake transactions or to trust anything in them.